# Почему в проекте, в решениях куча каких то файлов?

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Раньше вроде все было в одной папке и без кучи Unity.*, а начал новый проект получилось это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Исправил это через `Edir - preferences - External tool - Regenerate project file`
И все стало нормальным.